# Will this router and dovetail jig combo work?

Tags: routers

I am looking at getting this [router](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Milwaukee-2-1-4-Max-Horsepower-EVS-Multi-Base-Router-Kit-with-Plunge-Base-and-BodyGrip-Fixed-Base-5616-24/100609939?N=zvZ68y#.UfcCJWRxuQg) and this [dovetail jig.](http://www.homedepot.com/p/t/203162750?productId=203162750&storeId=10051&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&MERCH=REC-_-product-6-_-100671705-_-203162750-_-N#.UfcEWGRxuQg)

[image: Router Kit][image: Dovetail Jig]

These will be compatible with each other, right?

Answer (score 2):

These will be compatible with the correct bushing also known as a template guide.  I checked the description on Milwaukee's site and all it says is that it has an "4-point PM bushing", which is talking about the plunger, not the template guides. I didn't see it in the package contents.  If it isn't there you may need to get a bushing that fits the jig plates.  [Milwaukee](http://www.milwaukeetool.com/accessories/miscellaneous/49-54-0700) has a set that would have all the bushings you would need for this jig if you were to buy more plates for your jig. It runs around $40 on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00007FPIS).